# Detect if connected to the internet using a tethered phone in Python

Tags: python, wifi, tethering

I was wondering if there is a way to detect, from a python script, if the computer is connected to the internet using a tethered cell phone?

I have a Python script which runs a bunch of network measurement tests. Ideally, depending on the type of network the client is using (ethernet, wifi, LTE, ...) the tests should change. The challenge is how to get this information from the python client, with out asking the user to provide it. Especially detect tethering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, what I ended up doing was keeping the phone connected to my machine and used [ADB](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) to get this info. The command I run is:

```
 adb shell dumpsys netstats
```

[This](https://ulakmalr.wordpress.com/2014/11/15/get-android-device-information-using-adb-dumpsys/) is also a useful link.

Answer (score 1):

Normally not - from the computer's prospective the tethered cell phone is simply just another wifi router/provider.

You *might* be able to detect *some* of the phone carrier networks from the traceroute info to some known servers (DNS names or even IP address ranges of network nodes - they don't change that often).

If you have control over the phone tethering you could also theoretically use the phone's wifi SSID (or even IP address ranges) to identify tethering via individual/specific phones (not 100% reliable either unless you *know* that you can't get those parameters from other sources).